# Question about file location on UTL_HTTP.set_wallet parameters

Tags: oracle, rest, api, webservice-client

Hi I just had my dba create a wallet and populate it with the needed certificate.

I am doing this to set the wallet with the address he provided and running this on my local machine.

```
UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:C:\ORACLE\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin', 'pwd');
```

My question is when I run my stored proc, is it looking at the C drive of my local machine or the of the oracle server  as when I get to the next step which is the utl_http.begin_request i get a ora 29024 error indicating the certification failed.

Thanks,
John

Comment: you can't do that.  the wallet must exist on the server

Comment: Yes the wallet was installed on the server.. so when this gets called it will try to access that location on the server it's running on.. I guess the dba has to give me the name of the wallet.. that is just the directory of the wallet.